# How to get High quality RTSP Streaming URL using gData API

Tags: youtube-api, gdata-api, rtsp

Recently I have tried to get high quality RTSP Streamng using gData API

I have got only one clue from google, http://code.google.com/intl/ko/apis/youtube/2.0/reference.html#formatsp

Here it says I can get the video url only for low resolution (176x144),
Is there any way of archiving the url for high quality video?

Answer (score 2):

See this:
http://code.google.com/p/android-youtube-player/

This can easily be ported over to another platform, although currently is in Java / Android.

You get high quality video from this, have been looking for this for a really long time. The trick is to make a web request to YouTube requesting the different available streams, you actually get very personalized URL's, often directly from your ISP, very cool.

Comment: You'll run into some issues where the video can't play. Fix it with this:

https://code.google.com/p/android-youtube-player/issues/detail?id=14#c10

Comment: As of my testing today, this source does not give high-quality video; only low quality.

Comment: So there are two options that I know of, 1: video information URL, 2: Parse the YouTube page. There's an excellent perl script called youtubedown which deals with signatures and everything.. If you want to use the video information URL directly, look at
"http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=" + videoId + "&el=vevo" but keep in mind that signature encrypted videos will not work without first reverse engineering the signature.. Another option is of course to use the official YouTube api

Answer (score 1):

The GData feeds for YouTube do not expose the streams (which might not necessarily be RTSP streams), they will only [expose the urls for the streams which can be played on mobile devices](http://code.google.com/intl/ko/apis/youtube/2.0/reference.html#formatsp) (which are low quality).

That said, trying to store the high quality streams is currently (IIRC) a violation of the terms of service.